# How split a string a string based on position in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

String input:     `xxxxyyyyzzzz`

String output:    `xx xx yy yy zz zz`

Please split the above string in SQL Server. I am trying to use `replace` function something like

```
PARSENAME(REPLACE(@str, ',', '.'), 2)
```

but it's not working

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: Table is.. create table mtest(id int,strval varchar(150),strval1 varchar(150))
insert into mtest values(1,'a b c d','xxyyzzaa')
insert into mtest values(2,'e f','ccdd')
insert into mtest values(3,'g h i','llmmnn')
insert into mtest values(4,'j','kk') and answer

Comment: answer should be..1 xx
1 yy
1 zz
1 aa
2 cc
2 dd....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @str AS varchar(100) = 'xxxxyyyyzzzz';
DECLARE @i AS int = 1;
DECLARE @res AS varchar(250) = '';

WHILE (LEN(@str) + 1 >= @i)
BEGIN
  SET @res += SUBSTRING(@str, @i, 2) + ' ';
  SET @i = @i + 2;
END
SELECT @res as [output];
```

**Result**

```
+-------------------+
| output            |
+-------------------+
| xx xx yy yy zz zz | 
+-------------------+
```

[**Demo**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/526384/how-split-a-string-a-string-based-on-position-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

**[Using Numbers table..](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/)**

```
declare @string varchar(100)='xxxxyyyyzzzz'

;With cte
as
(select case when number%2<>0 then substring(@string,number,2) else null end as new from Numbers
where number<len(@string) 
)
select replace(stuff((select 
','+new 
 from cte where new is not null
 for xml path('')),1,1,''),',', ' ')
```

**Output:**
xx xx yy yy zz zz

Comment: @Ullas:I didn't get you

Comment: You edited your answer after I commented.. I asked about `Numbers` object

Comment: Ok,i was saying numbers table..gave the reference to link on how to create now

Answer (score 0):

Another way with CTE and [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(max) = 'xxxxyyyyzzzz'

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  @s as s,
            1 as lev
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  STUFF(s,3*lev,0,' '),
            lev+1
    FROM cte
    WHERE 3*lev < LEN(s)
)

SELECT top 1 s
FROM cte
ORDER BY lev desc
```

Output:

```
xx xx yy yy zz zz
```